# Dangling Transactions in MySQL Innodb

Tags: mysql, transactions

Suppose that I execute the following SQL statements:

```
start transaction;
insert into someTable (userId, amount) values (33, 44);
```

Notice that there is no Commit or Rollback at the end of this statement. I also do not have the option of requiring autoCommit being enabled.

How can a dba detect this sort of unfinished transaction? I've tried using 'show innodb status' but it provides too much information. I'm trying to find uncommitted transactions and force them to commit or rollback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocommit will not help you here, `start transaction` overrides it.

The dangling transactions will be **rolled back** as soon as the connection times out OR the client reconnects, whichever happens first.
There is no way to commit a dangling transaction, the only possible option is a rollback.

If you want to understand the InnoDB status output, see:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/17/show-innodb-status-walk-through/

Comment: How would I query mysql as a dba to see a list of dangling connection so I can roll them back? show processlist lists the dangling connection with command being "sleep"

Comment: @David, You can kill the connections I believe, let me get some food and I'll look it up.

Comment: True, but how would I know which connection to kill? When I list the connections, I see 10-20 connections which all are listed as "sleep". Only one of them has the dangling transaction so I don't want to kill all 10-20 of them (but that would effectively get the dangling connection).