# mysql and php PDO - what happens to an uncommited transaction if connection closes unexpectedly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539564/what-happens-to-an-uncommitted-transaction-when-the-connection-is-closed) but this question is different since the DBMS is different.

I'm developing something so, if some error is encountered, whole script terminates, sometimes while in a transaction. So what happens when a transaction isn't commited or rolled back? can it have long term effects on my machine? I once read that unclosed image resources do permanent long-term damage to the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen these? [MySQL rollback on transaction with lost/disconnected connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936699/mysql-rollback-on-transaction-with-lost-disconnected-connection) & [Dangling Transactions in MySQL Innodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851061/dangling-transactions-in-mysql-innodb)

sounds like they are rolled back after they timeout