# PDO transactions that do not get commit()ed or rollBack()ed

Tags: mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a code segment that looks like

```
try{

   $pdoLink->beginTransaction();

   //query1
   //query2

  if( $condition1 && $condition2 ){

    $pdoLink->commit();

  }
  else{

   $pdoLink->rollBack();

  }
}
catch(PDOException $e )
{
    $pdoLink->rollBack(); 
}
```

I have been wondering what will happen IF FOR ANY REASON, I invoke neither PDO::commit() nor PDO::rollBack() after initiating a transaction.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you don't commit or rollback, and then the script is allowed to complete and terminate execution?  That should result in the open transaction being rolled back when the script disconnects from the database in some RDBMS, but I would expect the behavior to be RDBMS-specific.  What do you use?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, yeah I use exactly that. As you can see from my code  excerpt, I usually do commit or rollback. Even in the event of an Exception, I rollback. But sometimes, the commit or rollback is in the calling code ( I do not know if this is good practice) and something may then go wrong that may bypass the commit or rollback block.  Anyway, you have pointed out what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: But is this dealing with MySQL, or something else? I don't have documentation to verify my assumption.

Comment: Here's a similar question specific to MySQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851061/dangling-transactions-in-mysql-innodb

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Yeah I am dealing with MySQL. I asked the question because I became curious and wanted to be on the safer side. Maybe someone with the idea of the documentation could come to the rescue.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I've checked the question. Although the OP there was concerned about InnoDB and DBA, the answer no doubt addresses my question in part. The main difference is, that is specific to the jobs of DBA whereas I am doing mine in code. Obviously I am not the DBA of my hosting company.